# Fresh install Debian Jessie over existing Debian Wheezy on laptop

Tags: debian, hardware, debian-installer

I am very new to Linux and any sort of communities for that matter so if I'm posting to the wrong place please let me know. I was hoping I could find a solution to my "problem".

I installed Debian "Wheezy" onto my laptop a while ago and have not touched it since. I don't care for any files on the laptop so I was hoping to just re-install the operating system to clear everything off and install Debian Jessie as a small web/ftp server. I'm hoping to dive more into Linux and start developing in Python.

I setup a new install DVD by burning an ISO for Debian 8.1.0 through Windows. The iso file would be "debian-8.1.0-amd64-source-DVD-1.iso" to be exact. I pop the disc into my laptop, make sure the BIOS is set to boot from the CD-ROM first, and reboot. I keep booting to the GRUB loader and when the system fully loads I am prompted to open the files of the install disc through File Explorer. It does not appear that my laptop is identifying the install disc as bootable. I'll press F12 to select what device to boot to and my CD-ROM does not show in the list.

The laptop is an Acer Aspire 5745 with an Intel Core i5-450M processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DVD you have contains part of the source code for Debian; it's not an installation disk.

You need one of the following images:

- [debian-8.1.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-8.1.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso) if you really want an installation DVD;
- [debian-8.1.0-amd64-netinst.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.1.0-amd64-netinst.iso) if you can install over the Internet (this is the recommended approach if you network hardware is supported);
- one of [the other installation CD images](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-cd/) if you want a smaller installation CD; [debian-8.1.0-amd64-CD-1.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.1.0-amd64-CD-1.iso) will install GNOME, [debian-8.1.0-amd64-kde-CD-1.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.1.0-amd64-kde-CD-1.iso) KDE, [debian-8.1.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.1.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso) and [debian-8.1.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.1.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso) XFCE.

To try Debian before installing it, you could also use one of the [live CD images](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/).

All of these should be correctly detected as bootable disks once burned.

Comment: And if you have a somewhat fast network-connection, it's usually best to just download the net-install version, or only the 1st cd-sized image. 99% of the users will only need software on the first disc anyway, and debian will download everything it needs from the network when you don't have it on disc.